# The use of the particle de

Tags: grammar, usage

How to answer this question 这是你弟弟？（朋友）
Is this correct or we should omit 的？“不是。这是我的朋友。”

Comment: See [To 的 or not to 的](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/32029/to-%e7%9a%84-or-not-to-%e7%9a%84) and [Why there is no 的 after 你 in 你国家的医院好吗?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/why-there-is-no-%e7%9a%84-after-%e4%bd%a0-in-%e4%bd%a0%e5%9b%bd%e5%ae%b6%e7%9a%84%e5%8c%bb%e9%99%a2%e5%a5%bd%e5%90%97)

Answer (score 1):

的 can be omitted in casual conversations (口語) when used as possessive means - 我的,他的,你的, and when there is no uncertainty on your relationship with the object.

- 那是我的家 = 那是我家
- 他是我的哥哥 = 他是我哥哥
- 這位是我的老師 = 這位是我老師

However, 的 can't be omitted when the possession of something needs to be ascertained, such as:

- 那是"我的東西", 那是"我的課本", 這是"我的狗", 那是"我父親的愛好", "我家門口的石獅子".

Comment: As in “我^家門口的石獅子”，one should say “那是我^課本上的笔记” with the first 的 omitted （marked as ^）

Comment: @imkzh The focus point of your example is "課本上的笔记" not the possession of the textbook by you, so 的 can be omitted. Actually, "那是課本上的笔记" means almost the same, 我 can be a redundant word in this case.