# Are 你美好的未来 and 你的美好未来 and 你迷人的眼神 and 你的迷人眼神 all correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence

You can say `你 的 美好 未来` = `Your bright future`.
And you can say `你 迷人 的 眼神` = `Your charming eyes`

Is `你 美好 的 未来` also correct?
Is `你 的 迷人 眼神` also correct?

Comment: yes, all your sentences are correct.

Answer (score 1):

"你美好的未来" and "你的美好未来" are reducted differently from the same sentences "你的美好的未来" (wordy)

> 你的美好的未来 (wordy)

> 你美好的未来 -- omitted 的 from 你的 (emphasize 美好的)

> 你的美好未来 -- omitted 的 from 美好的(emphasize 你的)

~

> 你的迷人的眼神 (wordy)

> 你迷人的眼神 -- omitted 的 from 你的 (emphasize 迷人的)

> 你的迷人眼神 -- omitted 的 from 迷人的 (emphasize 你的)

Please read [Why there is no 的 after 你 in 你国家的医院好吗?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/why-there-is-no-%e7%9a%84-after-%e4%bd%a0-in-%e4%bd%a0%e5%9b%bd%e5%ae%b6%e7%9a%84%e5%8c%bb%e9%99%a2%e5%a5%bd%e5%90%97)

and [When does an adjective require 的 to describe a noun?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39229/when-does-an-adjective-require-%e7%9a%84-to-describe-a-noun)

Comment: Without `你的`, are `美好未来` and `迷人眼神` alone still a correct usage? or you have to put  `的` in the middle if there is no `你` at the beginning?

Comment: 美好未来 and 迷人眼神 work because 美好 and 迷人  do not require 的 to be an adjective when applied to two characters noun https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39229/when-does-an-adjective-require-%e7%9a%84-to-describe-a-noun

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but I think "你 美好 的 未来" and "你 迷人 的 眼神" are focusing on "美好" and "迷人" more, and vaguely, "你 的 美好 未来" and "你 的 迷人 眼神" are focusing on "你的" more.